# Finding and replacing special characters in php

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character

Encoding makes this a tough thing to explain. I'm getting a string from an XML file using PHP. When I echo it I see a small black circle: • or • . Oh, stackoverflow renders these, sorry. I meant to say it's the ascii character "bull" or "#8226"

```
echo $str;
gets me:
[CIRCLE] wordswords [CIRCLE] more words [CIRCLE] still more words
```

How can I find this character using PHP? I want to explode on it. I can't search for a circle, and searching for 8226 or circ doesn't work. Do I have to use urlencode?

```
$str=url_encode($str);
$str=str_replace(%E2%80%A2,'-CIRCLE-',$str);
$str=url_decode($str);
$str=explode('-CIRCLE-');
```

Or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread: [Bullet "•" in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020488/bullet-in-xml). I think it will help your to find an answer.